# How can I use AngularJS filter in ngClass?

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

I'm curretly learning AngularJS and playing with the tutorial.

I'm modifying the tutorial example filter to return some string:

```
angular.module('phonecatFilters', []).filter('checkmark', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input ? 'true-class' : 'false-class';
  };
});
```

And I'd like to use that in `ngClass` as follows:

```
{{phone.trueVal  | checkmark}} <i ng-class="{{phone.trueVal  | checkmark }}"></i>
{{phone.falseVal | checkmark}} <i ng-class="{{phone.falseVal | checkmark }}"></i>
```

The results to:

```
true-class <i class="false-class">
false-class <i class="false-class">
```

Now.. while for simple view the filter works as expected.. why does it not work for ngClass? What whould be the correct way to use a filtered value in `ngClass` (and other like `ngSrc` etc).

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/s3x2F/

Comment: @OlivérKovács css rules are not applied.. http://jsfiddle.net/ja3h8/1/ why?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Zmetser/ja3h8/3/ Skip the ng-class an use class with the filter, or do the declarative approach: http://jsfiddle.net/Zmetser/3L3de/1/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your case, you should use `class` instead of `ng-class` because you ***render the class name directly on the html*** without evaluation.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <i class="{{phone.trueVal  | checkmark }}">{{phone.trueVal  | checkmark}}</i>
   <i class="{{phone.falseVal | checkmark }}">{{phone.falseVal | checkmark}}</i>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ja3h8/2/)

Comment: i don't know why it does not work on AngularJS tutorial project.. but I see it working in your demo so I guess it must be some silly mistake on my end somewhere in the code...

Comment: ngClass takes either an object or a string, so you can do ng-class=" 'myClass'+item.priority "
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14644299/1702919

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me. Just stared with AngularJS so I'm not sure if the functionality was added as part of an update since this question is a couple years old.

```
ng-class="{ 'has-error': (login.form | validField:'username') }"
```

After adding the parentheses, it worked.