# how to add class using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to add a class to the i tag after clicking of button. how can I achieve this using angular js.

```
<button type="button" title="Like" ng-click="countLikes(product.title)" class="btn btn-compare">
   <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
</button>


 $scope.countLikes = function (e) {
      console.log(e);
  }
```

I wanted output like this. Added exampleClass to the i tag

```
    <button type="button" title="Like" ng-click="countLikes(product.title)" class="btn btn-compare">
   <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up exampleClass"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643836/dynamic-class-in-angular-js

Comment: No problem, btw I did not add any commet to link, because explanation in that topic seems to be nice and clean :)

Answer (score 1):

use `ng-class` directive

```
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" ng-class="{'exampleClass' : buttonClicked}"></i>

$scope.countLikes = function (e) {
      $scope.buttonClicked = true;
      console.log(e);
}
```

when `buttonClicked` is true `i` element will get the `exampleClass` css class

Answer (score 0):

```js
<button type="button" title="Like" ng-click="countLikes(product.title)" class="btn btn-compare">
   <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" ng-class="{'exampleClass': isClick}"></i>
</button>

$scope.isClick = false;
$scope.countLikes = function (e) {
    $scope.isClick = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer

```
<button type="button" title="Like"  class="btn btn-compare" ng-click="(myLike = myLike === 'fa-thumbs-o-up' ? 'fa-thumbs-up' : 'fa-thumbs-o-up'); countLikes(product.title)";>
    <i class="fa" ng-class="myLike"></i>
</button>

 $scope.myLike = "fa-thumbs-o-up";
```