# How do I bind this scope variable to a ng-class attribute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

This seems like it should be fairly straightforward, however I'm absolutely out of options

In my view I have:

```
<div>{{selectedTheme.theme}}</div>
<ion-nav-view ng-class="selectedTheme.theme" name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
```

where the first `div` outputs the class as expected. However, I cannot get the class to get inserted into the `ion-nav-view` element!

The resulting mark-up is as follows:

```
<div class="ng-binding">Dark</div>
<ion-nav-view ng-class="selectedTheme.theme" name="menuContent" class="view-container" nav-view-transition="ios" nav-view-direction="none" nav-swipe="">></ion-nav-view>
```

Any input at all would be immense!

PS: In addition, setting it simply with `class` works fine.

Comment: I say you should go for a directive here and use `element.addClass()`. You should take a look at [this question too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643836/dynamic-class-in-angular-js)

Comment: @JamesP, that is just not correct. `ng-class` accepts an expression that if evaluated to string of space-delimited class names or an array, uses these values as is. Only, when the expression is an object, the property is used as a class if it has a truthy value

Comment: if you just want the name of the class add {{}} and your good, Like : `ng-class="{{selectedTheme.theme}}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Angular `ng-class`uses an expression or just a plain old string. You can do things like:

1. Add/Remove classes based on Angular variables
2. Add/Remove classes based on evaluated expressions
3. Bind single or multiple classes based on dynamic data

You can just add an Angular variable to `ng-class` and that is the class that will be used for that element. So in your case, if `selectedTheme.theme` yields the exact `class` name you wish to use, then it should work fine.

```
<ion-nav-view ng-class="varHoldingClassName" name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
```

So here's a full example in action:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Angular!';
    $scope.selectedTheme = {
         'coalTheme': 'textColor'
    };
}
```

```css
.textColor{
    color: red;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-class="selectedTheme.coalTheme">Hello, {{name}}!</div>
</div>
</div>
```