# How to add a unique class name for each object in an array with Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I'm iterating over a collection of objects using ng-repeat to create multiple anchor tags and I want to apply a class name equal to the *name* value of each object plus the word "icon". E.g. for the object { "name" : "square" }, I'd like the  tag to have the class="square-icon".

What is the best way to accomplish this?

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <a ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class=??(I'm not sure what to put here)?? 
  </a>
</div>
```

JSON Object example

```
[{ name: "square" }, 
{ name: "hexagon" }, ... ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to add a class with plain `class` attribute.

Try `<a ... class="{{someObject.name}}-icon">`.

For flexibility, you might want to [implement custom function which returns a proper `ng-class` value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643836/dynamic-class-in-angular-js).

Comment: Great, thank you for both suggestions. For my needs, the simpler solution was sufficient.