# How to display the span once the value is entered in input field? Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a scope variable defined in my controller, initially the value of my scope variable is empty.

I binded the ng-model to the input field and added ng-show to the span which needs to be display, once the value is entered in the input field.

When I entered a value in the input field, the span is not getting displayed.

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ng-form-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('head')).append(angular.element('<base href="' + window.location.pathname + '" />'));
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="formExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('formExample', [])
    .controller('FormController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.userType = '';
    }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="FormController" class="my-form">
  userType: <input name="input" ng-model="userType">
  <span ng-show="myForm.input.length>0">show me!</span><br>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the demo Link:

[Demo Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qvyqt8liB7BhLV3tlVGX?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the scope variable **`userType's`** length, It should be,

```
<span ng-show="userType.length>0">show me!</span><br>
```

[`DEMO APP`](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZhT1DG0vsfcgpLaPrAnZ?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan

Comment: @M-S Mark as answer if it has helped you

Comment: Definitely, Just waiting for the mark option to be enabled

Comment: How do I append class dynamically to the another span if the userType.length>0 
https://plnkr.co/edit/vPuUWsFBtYKdxTKvXQSe?p=preview

Comment: you can use a function to apply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643836/dynamic-class-in-angular-js

Answer (score 0):

Just check the input modal value as below,

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ng-form-production</title>
  

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('head')).append(angular.element('<base href="' + window.location.pathname + '" />'));
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="formExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('formExample', [])
.controller('FormController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.userType = '';
}]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="FormController" class="my-form">
  userType: <input name="input" ng-model="userType">
  <span ng-show="userType">show me!</span><br>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```